# Spam relaying through my mail server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, spam

Would anyone mind having a quick look at the header below to help me identify if our mail server is acting as a relay for spam (or something else)? It was received by an RBL a few days ago, and its got me worried that I've incorrectly set something up.

I'm running a Win2003 Server box with Exchange 2003 on top of it.

I have enabled "filter recipients who are not in the Directory", and setup relay restrictions to only allow our external sites to relay through the mail server.

I also have a watchguard device filtering all inbound mail as our spam solution. I am considering  enabling outgoing spam filtering as well to see if that fixes the problem; but I wanted to pose the question here first before doing that.

```
(envelope-from <mrsjoybrown1414@yahoo.com>) 
id 1QCusr-0004pB-Pw 
for victim@smtp.example; Thu, 21 Apr 2011 10:29:30 -0400 
Received: from <our.mail.server> ([our.mail.server.ip]:1972) 
by obfuscated2 with esmtp (Exim 4.71) 
(envelope-from <mrsjoybrown1414@yahoo.com>) 
id 1QCusr-0004ow-Cn 
for victim@smtp.example; Thu, 21 Apr 2011 10:29:29 -0400 
Received: from User ([76.97.117.199]) by <our.mail.server> with Microsoft SMTPSVC (6.0.3790.4675); 
Fri, 22 Apr 2011 00:08:29 +1000 
Reply-To: <mrsjoybrown1515@gmail.com> 
From: "MRS JOY BROWN"<mrsjoybrown1414@yahoo.com> 
Subject: Greetings in the name of God   
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2011 15:07:19 +0100 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
charset="Windows-1251" 
Bcc:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for open relay from this site. Put in your email domain name and click SMTP test:

http://mxtoolbox.com/index.aspx

I've seen this happen once for me and I found that it was acutally due to a poor service account password. The following site gives a GREAT run down of testing, finding and cleaning up any mess.

http://exchange.sembee.info/2003/smtp/spam-cleanup.asp

Answer (score 0):

Go here to see if you are misconfigured:

http://www.checkor.com/

Comment: Crap, thanks for the replies guys.
I kinda forgot I posted the question here. Definately not showing up as an open relay. will keep searching.